# Youtube videos not playing in videogular2 Plugin

Tags: angular, videogular

I've installed Videogular2 into my Angular-CLI application and followed the steps to integrate video into the page. When I give the source of local video it is working fine, but when I give source of Youtube or any other external video it is not playing. I've specified type as video/mp4.